# Как поменять местами элементы в двусвязном списки(С/С++)

Tags: c++, c

Надо поменять 2-ой и предпоследний элемент двусвязного списка

Comment: Найдите и почитайте инфу как работать с двухсвязными списками.

Comment: А какую либу используете для работы c двухсвязным списком?

Comment: Что вы читали по этому вопросу? Вот http://www.sql.ru/forum/727050/si-kak-pomenyat-dva-sosednih-elementa-spiska из топ 10 гугла.

Comment: Стоит нарисовать элементы списка вместе с соседями на бумаге  и подумать, как правильно разорвать, сохранить связи вперёд и назад и потом восстановить их для новых элементов

Comment: Вот простой пример работы с двусвязным списком: https://pastebin.com/mScMkkdy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проще всего поменять данные в элементах списка, если нужно все таки переставлять элементы то задача более сложная...нам понадобится 4 переменных где мы будем хранить промежуточные данные указателей. Если элементы стоят рядом друг с другом то порядок замены указателей будет такой (написано на Java но идея должна быть ясна)

```
        tempMAX.next = tempE.next;

        tempE.prev = tempMAX.prev;

        tempMAX.prev = tempE ;

        tempE.next = tempMAX ;

        tempMAX.next.prev = tempMAX ;

        tempE.prev.next = tempE ;

        tempMAX = tempMAX.prev;

        tempE = tempMAX.next ;
```

если элементы не соседние то порядок смены указателей отличается двумя последними строками
        // копируем ссылки в временные переменные

```
  tempNext = tempE.next ; 

  tempPrev = tempE.prev ;

  MAXnext = tempMAX.next ;

  MAXprev = tempMAX.prev ;

 // присваиваем новые ссылки ячейкам (элементам) 

  tempE.next = MAXnext ;

  tempE.prev = MAXprev ;

  tempMAX.next = tempNext ;

  tempMAX.prev = tempPrev ;

  // меняем ссылки у соседей 

  tempMAX.next.prev = tempMAX ;

  tempE.prev.next = tempE ;

  tempMAX.prev.next = tempMAX ; 

  tempE.next.prev = tempE ;
```

Comment: в моем списке есть заголовок , который указывает на первый элемент и на последний, то есть список закольцованный, если у вас есть начало и конец списка то нужно предусмотреть еще 2 варианта в случае если элементы стоят в начале или в конце.